# How to create mount path in Azure container instance for LUIS setup

Tags: azure-language-understanding, azure-container-instances

I am trying to setup LUIS Image on Azure container instanse. i had setup Enviornment variables like Eula,API Key and Endpoint
But I am not sure how to create a mount path /input where i can plance my LUIS Exported file.

Please let me know if anyone has info on this?

Comment: refer to this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-container-howto?tabs=v3

Comment: I checked this already . this doc basically shows how to run it locally. i had already achived this..but now am trying to run this on Azure container instanse. there i have doubt how to map correct mount path for /input folder.

Comment: are you still facing this issue  ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/containers/azure-container-instance-recipe?tabs=portal Please refer this

Comment: Thanks for sharing . I am able to achive that.

Comment: hello @SanK, Are you still facing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Export your LUIS app using the export for container option. You 've done it, make sure is .gz and that's your language understanding model file.
   Maks sure you did it *before* creating the container.
   You can export a trained or a published LUIS app.
2. Upload the exported model file to an Azure File Share. The container instance mounts the file share to access the model file.
3. Deploy the container using Azure Command Line Interface (CLI) and a YAML. The YAML file must contains the details of the mount point for the File Share and all other required settings for the LUIS container including the container registry and container image name.